# Extracting int values in dataframe cell including NAN with error TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Tags: python, string, object, dataframe, indexing

I have a code which searchs the internet and finding urls including certain phrases, tries to open the urls and if it can, inputs them into a Dataframe called Mastersurl, looking like this:

```
>>> Masterurls
 Matches     Searching for  \
0       0.0  Green Bond Index 
1       Na  Green Bond Index
2       1  Green Bond
```

if it cannot open, it returns "Na" in the "Matches" Column. I have tried to find the rows in which columns have values bigger than 0 by trying:

```
 Masterurls.Matches>0
Masterurls['Matches']>0
float(Masterurls['Matches'])>0
int(Masterurls['Matches'])>0
```

checking the type `(Masterurls)= object`
all return errors: `unorderable types:str()>int()`
if I change the "Na" values to -1, the type `(Mastervalues['Matches'])` changes to Float and the code runs. How can I tell it to check cells in column "Matches" of dataframe Mastersurl in which values are bigger than 0, and not "Na"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use [to_numeric()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) method:

```
Masterurls.loc[pd.to_numeric(Masterurls.Matches, errors='coerce') > 0]
```

Demo:

```
In [146]: Masterurls
Out[146]:
  Matches     Searching for
0     0.0  Green Bond Index
1      Na  Green Bond Index
2       1        Green Bond

In [147]: Masterurls.loc[pd.to_numeric(Masterurls.Matches, errors='coerce') > 0]
Out[147]:
  Matches Searching for
2       1    Green Bond

In [148]: Masterurls[pd.to_numeric(Masterurls.Matches, errors='coerce') > 0]
Out[148]:
  Matches Searching for
2       1    Green Bond
```